# How do i minify the output of php file, which include another php inside?

Tags: php, html, minify

I have file header.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Another file footer.php

```
<p>footerlink</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally i include these both file in my index.php as follows

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Which output as below in browser

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p> <p>footerlink</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**How can I minify the this output as below expected result in index.php?**

Expected result

```
<html><head></head><body><p>Hello world</p><p>footerlink</p></body></html>
```

Comment: If you minify `header.php` and `footer.php`, the result will be minified.

Comment: Any way to minify in index.php? As i have multiple files included in index.php